# Call to a member function setTemplate() on a non-object in home page

Tags: module, blocks

My home.phtml file

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('banner/Monblock')
->setTemplate('banner/afficher.phtml')->toHtml();
```

my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <test_adminhtml_index_index>
     <reference name="content">
             <block type="banner/Myblock"  name="afficher_monbloc"
                  template="banner/afficher.phtml"/>
                   <block type="banner/adminhtml_grid" name="banner" />
      </reference>

   </test_adminhtml_index_index>

   <reference name="content">
             <block type="banner/Monblock"  name="afficher_monbloc"
                  template="banner/afficher.phtml"/>
                   <block type="banner/adminhtml_grid" name="banner" />
      </reference>

       <default>
          <reference name="content">
          </reference>
      </default>
      <banner_index>
           <reference name="content">
               <block type="banner/Monblock"  name="afficher_monbloc"
                  template="banner/afficher.phtml"/>
                  <block type="test/test"  name="test"
                          template="test/tes2.phtml" />
           </reference>
      </banner_index>
</layout>
```

My block file

```
class Banner_Banner_Block_Monblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
     public function methodblock()
     {
         return 'informations about my block !!' ;
     }
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        <Banner_Banner>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Banner_Banner>
     </modules>
     <frontend>
       <routers>
          <banner>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Banner_Banner</module>
                 <frontName>banner</frontName>
              </args>
           </banner>
       </routers>
       <layout>
            <updates>
                <Banner_Banner>
                    <file>Banner.xml</file>
                </Banner_Banner>
            </updates>
        </layout>   
    </frontend>
    <admin>
     <routers>
         <banner>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
               <module>Banner_Banner</module>
               <frontName>admintest</frontName>
            </args>
         </banner>
      </routers>
 </admin>
 <adminhtml>
   <layout>
      <updates>
          <banner>
              <file>banner.xml</file>
           </banner>
      </updates>
   </layout>
   <menu>
      <banner translate="title" module="adminhtml">
         <title>My Banner</title>
         <sort_order>100</sort_order>
         <children>
             <set_time>
                   <title>Add Banner</title>
                   <action>admintest/adminhtml_index</action>
              </set_time>
          </children>
       </banner>
    </menu>
</adminhtml>
     <global>
      <models>
<banner>
     <class>Banner_Banner_Model</class>
     <resourceModel>Banner_mysql4</resourceModel>
 </banner>
<banner_mysql4>
     <class>Banner_Banner_Model_Mysql4</class>
     <entities>
         <banner>
           <table>banner</table>
         </banner>
      </entities>
</banner_mysql4>
</models>
    <!-- allow the plugin to read and write -->
<resources>
        <!-- connection to write -->
        <test_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </test_write>
        <!-- connection to read -->
       <test_read>
          <connection>
             <use>core_read</use>
          </connection>
       </test_read>
</resources>
 <!-- -/- -->

            <blocks> 
              <Banner>

              <class>Banner_Banner_Block</class>
             </Banner>

            </blocks>

     </global> 
</config>
```

Comment: can you post the `config.xml` file of your module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change this part of your `config.xml`:

```
<blocks> 
     <Banner>
         <class>Banner_Banner_Block</class>
     </Banner>
</blocks>
```

to

```
<blocks> 
     <banner><!-- lowercase letters here -->
         <class>Banner_Banner_Block</class>
     </banner>
</blocks>
```

then call the block like this:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('banner/monblock')->setTemplate('banner/afficher.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `config.xml` file, you should have a code like this

FILE: `app\code\local\Banner\Banner\etc\configx.xml`

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <banner> <!-- this is block alias name. VERY IMPORTANT ! -->
             <class>Banner_Banner_Block</class>
        </banner>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

This defines your custom module block section. Without this, Magento will not understand where should it look for your custom blocks. So make sure, this code exist.

Kindly note the block alias name. It should be `banner` in this case. Then you can now refer your custom block like this.

```
 banner/monblock
```

Note all letters should be in small letter.

But I recommend you to change block alias name to `banner_banner`. That is the best practice. In general, it should be `namespace_modulename`. Now you can refer you block with

```
 banner_banner/monblock
```

In either way, you need to change this in everywhere. Means in layout file as well as in home.phtml file.

Answer (score 0):

There issue with block type `banner/Monblock` .it should be in `banner/monblock`.Block class  type should be small letter.

Also Suggest `used Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template class instead Mage_Core_Block_Template`  because `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template is add more functions` which will `suitable with backend`

The contend after  `</test_adminhtml_index_index>` should with in handler

```
<reference name="content">
             <block type="banner/Monblock"  name="afficher_monbloc"
                  template="banner/afficher.phtml"/>
                   <block type="banner/adminhtml_grid" name="banner" />
      </reference>
```

`class Banner_Banner_Block_Monblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template` change to

```
class Banner_Banner_Block_Monblock extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template.
```

Comment: Not Working I am trying but same error

Comment: I didnt get you

Comment: can you tell layout file location ?